# Node.js + github pages

Tags: node.js, github, github-pages

I am trying to host my node.js file on GitHub pages, But I dont see an option do do that. Is it possible to host node.js files using GitHub pages? Or is there any other other website I can use to host the files?

Comment: You can use Node script to generate static contents that are deployed to pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub pages only host static resources. You can not have server-side apps hosted on there. You can host it somewhere else and call it from a GitHub pages file!

Reference:https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages